# Comparing two explanatory variables explanatory variables

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

I am new to stats, I am working on a problem and I need some direction.

I have a binary dataset and I have three explanatory variables x,y, and z that I want to analyze. There is no guarantee of independence between any of them. I would like to perform a test to compare the explanatory power of two of them e.g x,y. I think that if for example, I do logistic regression with x,z, and another y,z and compare the goodness of fit or I compare coefficients in one logistic regression with all variables, it wouldn't work because none of the variables are independent.

So I am not sure how to proceed.

Please let me know if the post needs more information/clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an interaction term. So if your response is w, your formula would be $w \sim x + y + x*y$ if you just wanted to use x and y as predictors, or $w \sim  x + y + z + x*y + y*z + x*z + x*y*z$. Usually three factors interactions aren’t common so you could omit the last term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, let's say I add the interactions how would I see which variable has more explanatory power ? If for example, I check the coefficients, how would I interpret the ones for interactions?

Comment: @jm96 first you need to check if the pvalue is significant for each term. then you can look at the *magnitude* of the coefficient. and then the interaction term for *xy* can be interpreted as depending on how much *y* there is, then changes in *x* will have different results than if the interaction term were not there

Comment: So how should I analyze the coefficients. If for example the magnitude for y is slightly higher than that for x but the magnitude for the intersection is much higher. Would I say y has more explanatory power ?, assuming all p values are significant. If so wouldn't that assume that y and x are  equally important in the relation between the interaction and the dependent variable ? (I guess not necessarily equal but I think it conveys the assumption)

Comment: @jm96 im not sure. if you have like logit(w)=3+5x+6y+25xy then if x=0 then there is no interaction and it becomes 3+6y but if x=1 then it becomes 8+31y so y has more explanatory power. but if youre just saying which one has more explanatory power then id guess they are roughly the same, not sure tho